# Экспорт по определённому значению в столбце

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Как выделить для экспорта в таблице столбец, чтобы экспорт был только по определенному значению?
Грубо говоря, есть таблица, там столбец, нужен экспорт в XML только тех `entries`, которые содержат определённое слово.

Answer (score 1):

Делаете необходимый `SQL` запрос с выбранной таблицей, и внизу там есть пункт `Использование результатов запроса` там есть экспорт.

Comment: Это понятно, я уже сделал такой экспорт. Имею ввиду другое.

Comment: тогда уточните вопрос, вы не знаете как выбрать нужные значения? `select * from name_table where name_row="text"` после выбранные данные экспортируете

Comment: SELECT * FROM `data_catalog` WHERE `data_object="chl"`  пишет #1054 - Unknown column 'data_object="chl"' in 'where clause'

Comment: нету такого столбца `data_object` смотрите структуру таблицы, как правильно называется поле

Comment: Да я уже всё перепробовал. Мне кажется проблема в синтаксе. Обычную команду прорабатывает, до столбца докатывается:  SELECT *
FROM `data_catalog`
WHERE `obj_type`
LIMIT 0 , 30   а дальше где = он не обрабатывает

Comment: Покажите скриншот структуры таблицы

Comment: https://s31.postimg.org/47cvm738b/obj.jpg   из obj_type нужно экспортировать только со словом chl

Comment: `SELECT * FROM data_catalog WHERE obj_type="chl"` - вот такой запрос выдает ошибку? просто вначале вы писали `WHERE data_object="chl"` - на скриншоте я не вижу поля с именем `data_object`

Comment: Решено. Спасибо